# Python SSL communication hangs on read, then issues an error 54 - connection reset by peer

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, connection-reset

I'm making a web services call to a Microsoft CRM web service using Python/suds/python-ntlm, and my call to the service is blocking on an SSL read. The CRM service provider provides both a testing and a production service, and I can contact the testing service just fine (although it doesn't have useful data on it) but the main service just blocks.

This is the stack trace, after I interrupt the process:

```
;; This buffer is for notes you don't want to save, and for Lisp evaluation.
;; If you want to create a file, visit that file with C-x C-f,
;; then enter the text in that file's own buffer.

INFO:root:Getting WSDL from file:///Users/crose/projects/aed/2366/crm/services/metadata.wsdl
DEBUG:suds.client:sending to (https://service.host/MSCrmServices/2007/MetadataService.asmx)
message:
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns0:Body>
      <ns1:Execute>
         <ns1:Request xsi:type="ns1:RetrieveAttributeRequest">
            <ns1:MetadataId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ns1:MetadataId>
            <ns1:EntityLogicalName>opportunity</ns1:EntityLogicalName>
            <ns1:LogicalName>new_typeofcontact</ns1:LogicalName>
            <ns1:RetrieveAsIfPublished>false</ns1:RetrieveAsIfPublished>
         </ns1:Request>
      </ns1:Execute>
   </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
DEBUG:suds.client:headers = {'SOAPAction': u'"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/Execute"', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:sending:
URL:https://service.host/MSCrmServices/2007/MetadataService.asmx
HEADERS: {'SOAPAction': u'"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/Execute"', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml', 'Content-type': 'text/xml', 'Soapaction': u'"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/Execute"'}
MESSAGE:
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns0:Body>
      <ns1:Execute>
         <ns1:Request xsi:type="ns1:RetrieveAttributeRequest">
            <ns1:MetadataId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ns1:MetadataId>
            <ns1:EntityLogicalName>opportunity</ns1:EntityLogicalName>
            <ns1:LogicalName>new_typeofcontact</ns1:LogicalName>
            <ns1:RetrieveAsIfPublished>false</ns1:RetrieveAsIfPublished>
         </ns1:Request>
      </ns1:Execute>
   </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
  C-c C-cTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "sudstest2.py", line 40, in <module>
    attr = metadata_client.service.Execute(mdRequest(*picklist))
  File "/Users/crose/virtualenv/advanis/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 539, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/crose/virtualenv/advanis/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 598, in invoke
    result = self.send(msg)
  File "/Users/crose/virtualenv/advanis/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 623, in send
    reply = transport.send(request)
  File "/Users/crose/virtualenv/advanis/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/transport/https.py", line 64, in send
    return  HttpTransport.send(self, request)
  File "/Users/crose/virtualenv/advanis/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 77, in send
    fp = self.u2open(u2request)
  File "/Users/crose/virtualenv/advanis/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 118, in u2open
    return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 429, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/crose/virtualenv/advanis/src/python-ntlm/ntlm/HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.py", line 96, in http_error_401
    return self.http_error_authentication_required('www-authenticate', req, fp, headers)
  File "/Users/crose/virtualenv/advanis/src/python-ntlm/ntlm/HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.py", line 35, in http_error_authentication_required
    return self.retry_using_http_NTLM_auth(req, auth_header_field, None, headers)
  File "/Users/crose/virtualenv/advanis/src/python-ntlm/ntlm/HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.py", line 80, in retry_using_http_NTLM_auth
    response = h.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 986, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 391, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 349, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 397, in readline
    data = recv(1)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 96, in <lambda>
    self.recv = lambda buflen=1024, flags=0: SSLSocket.recv(self, buflen, flags)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 217, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 136, in read

KeyboardInterrupt
```

Eventually, I get a connection error 54 - connection reset by peer - from this, after waiting a fair amount of time.

What's my best bet for debugging this?

Comment: I have a very similar problem. An answer to this question would be awesome ...

Comment: Which version of python? Not sure it's relevant, but prior to about 2.6 there was a bug in the ssl library which disabled the timeout while doing the ssl handshake.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is it is getting something in the http headers that are messing it up.  You might try making the same call with wget or curl with the debug/verbose settings on and see what they are getting back.

It could also be something with logging in to the service to many times in quick succession.  I have ran into this before, but its might not be but its something else to check into.